# How to use Java Generic Class in MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab

I am new for MATLAB, I would like to use a java generic class in MATLAB.

OS: Windows 7 64 bit, MATLAB R2013a, Java version 1.6.

**On Java Part:**

```
public  List<List<Integer>> last=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    public void list_method(List<Integer> points){
    last.add(points);
    recordedSample.getMatrix().add(last); //Sample class object
}
```

---

**On MATLAB Part:**

```
list =java.util.ArrayList();
while(1)
    matrix = [right_lip_x;right_lip_y;left_lip_xy;left_lip_yx;upper_lip_x;upper_lip_y;bottom_‌​lip_x;bottom_lip_y]; %here 1-by-8 matrix

for k=1:length(matrix)
    list.add(int32(matrix(k)));
    end 
end
```

I would like expected result list like : `[1,2,3,2,2,2,2,1] [442,22,2,2,2,2,4,12] etc..`

**Note :**
Please look at my reference link [Expected Result](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/121158-error-unexpected-matlab-operator-arraylist-list-integer) another result [using Java Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463625/using-java-generic-classes-in-matlab#) I could not understand, please let me know?